# D3 multiline plot x axis returns NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a XY plot with the X axis having time unit on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/VfcLa/

The time is stored inside the data collection in ISO format and I'm parsing it using:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;
```

The x axis scale is generated using a time scale function:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
```

The x axis domain is defined like:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data.e1), function (d) {        return d.time;    });
```

And the plot lines are generated using the following functions:

```
   var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.time);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
        });
```

Every time the `x()` function is called with a parsed ISO date argument it returns `NaN`.

d="MNaN,0.3727223712260468LNaN,3.551619373753615CNaN,6.730516376281183,NaN,13.088310381336319,NaN,15.327467421250939CNaN,17.56662446116556,NaN,15.687144535939666,NaN,12.446127138207757CNaN,9.205109740475848,NaN,4.602554870237924,NaN,5.316237018898292CNaN,6.02991916755866,NaN,12.05983833511732,NaN,17.974294680466606CNaN,23.888751025815896,NaN,29.687744548955813,NaN,29.192971911030863CNaN,28.698199273105914,NaN,21.9096604741161,NaN,16.400308154832988CNaN,10.890955835549873,NaN,6.660789995973459,NaN,7.246710113817281CNaN,7.832630231661104,NaN,13.234636306925163,NaN,34.457639028148215CNaN,55.68064174937127,NaN,92.72464111655331,NaN,93.00921342738123CNaN,93.29378573820912,NaN,56.818930992682894,NaN,36.501416168287236CNaN,16.18390134389157,NaN,12.02372644062648,NaN,9.943638988993934LNaN,7.8635515373613885"

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong with my definition of the x axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_extent) method takes a data array as input argument and an accessor method as second argument. The accessor tells which property of the array should be used to compute the extent. You probably want to define the domain as

```
// Use the time extent as domain
x.domain(d3.extent(data.e1, function (d) { return d.time; }));
```

Regards,